# Button doesn't repeat when action modifies view condition

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've implemented a custom stepper with the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var count: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let amount = count {
                Button {
                    count = amount - 1
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                        .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
                        .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                        .foregroundStyle(.background, .tint)
                }
                
                Text(amount.formatted())
                    .monospacedDigit()
                    .fixedSize()
                
                Button {
                    count = amount + 1
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .symbolVariant(.circle.fill)
                        .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                        .foregroundStyle(.background, .tint)
                }
            }
        }
        .buttonRepeatBehavior(.enabled)
    }
}
```

I expect that when I hold down one of the buttons, the counter increases or decreases repeatedly. However, it only increments or decrements once. That said, if I make `count` non-optional and change the actions to modify it directly, everything works as expected

In my app, my data model is more complex than to be able to refactor away the conditional, so how can I make this work?

I've already tried assigning each button a static `id`, but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the views inside the `if` to another view:

```
struct MyStepper: View {
    @Binding var amount: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            amount -= 1
        } label: { ... }
        
        Text(...)
        
        Button {
            amount += 1
        } label: { ... }
    }
}
```

In `ContentView`, you can get a non-optional binding from `count` like this:

```
HStack {
    if let amount = Binding($count) {
        MyStepper(amount: amount)
            .buttonRepeatBehavior(.enabled)
    }
}
```